# How to run a program in SSH?

Tags: ssh, exe

So I want to run an .exe in SSH but can't figure out, help please?

I'm trying to run a server for my game i'm making and need this on my vps so anyone can connect, but can't figure out how to run it in SSH on my vps.

Comment: .exe are almost always Windows executables. SSH is almost exclusively used in UNIX-like OSes. Thoye two don't fit together.

Comment: Hardly. SSH is everywhere. But the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @tripleee: while SSH on Windows exists, it's still somewhat rare, in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

SSH is a protocol and will, by itself, never run any program. Depending on the Shell you're running inside SSH and the operating system in use you will start your executable:

```
Linux: ./program
Windows: program.exe
```

Note: exe usually indicates a Windows program. Most Linux/Unix servers have SSH access, while Microsoft servers usually don't. Are you trying to start a windows exe on a Linux machine? That will not work (ever). Unless it is a .NET executable, in which case you can start in using the mono-framework.

Answer (score 1):

You need **./** before the program name, like this

```
./program.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux: This will run a series of commands remotely into a remote machine with ssh (make sure your username has direct access and password is not required):

> ssh remotemachine ' command1 | command2 | command3 '

Answer (score 0):

For windows, you can use the following command:

```
ssh username@remotePcIP "\file.exe"
```